# Is quantum computation possible in a superdeterministic universe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computer, determinism, bells-inequality

I've seen many [renowned scientists arguing that the universe is superdeterministic](https://ora.ox.ac.uk/objects/uuid:95fdf72b-168f-49dc-a1d2-7fec5cf51535/download_file?safe_filename=Hossenfelder%2520and%2520Palmer%2520Rethinking%2520superdeterminism.pdf&type_of_work=Journal+article), but superdeterminism is a "hidden variable" theory. Is this compatible with the concept of quantum computation?

Comment: Many scientists? There’s literally just one… who constantly misrepresents what superdeterminism means to her popsci audience so that they think every other option is obviously stupid.

Comment: I think pointing to a single paper with two authors doesn't make the first point strongly. As of today, there are merely hundreds of papers on [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22superdeterminism%22&btnG=) that explicitly mention "superdeterminism" at all. Only a subset of those can be arguing for superdeterministic theories.

Comment: Here is a popular science video by Hossenfelder on superdeterminism: [*Does Superdeterminism save Quantum Mechanics? Or does it kill free will and destroy science?*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytyjgIyegDI)

Comment: Here is (what appears to be) a seminar recording of Hossenfelder on superdeterminism: [*Sabine Hossenfelder on Rethinking Superdeterminism of Quantum Mechanics*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MgpFF8Cd1eY).

Comment: I actually was initially referring to Gerard’t Hoof (who is a Nobel prize winner, and a reviewer of the paper). However, you are correct - there are very few scientists today that truly believe in superdeterminism. I am a Everettian myself. To anyone interested in a more neutral video on the topic, please see [this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnKzt6Xq-w4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, a superdeterminist would say that their position is purely a philosophical interpretation of quantum mechanics, and they don't make any different predictions about the outcomes of experiments.

So, yes, I think a superdeterminist would be happy to assume that the "superdeterminer" who set up the state of the Universe originally did so in a way that the results of quantum computations came out the same way that they would under any other interpretation of quantum mechanics.

One could imagine this working since in order for quantum computer to work, you must set up the quantum algorithm so that the most likely outcome (according to quantum mechanics) is that the computer ends the algorithm in a state corresponding to the correct result of the computation. The work needed to get the answer is in designing and implementing algorithm, it's not the case that the "superdeterminer" has to compute the right answer themselves or can make a mistake in what results they give you, so long as they are obeying the laws of quantum mechanics (which they are, by assumption).

That's me trying to be as objective as possible. But to give my 2 cents: I recommend that you don't spend too much time thinking about superdeterminism. It is utterly void of intellectual content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you expand your two cents a little bit more?

Comment: @Guilherme I'm not sure if there are any superdeterminists here I will get in trouble with. But superdeterminism, to me, is the ultimate ["God of the gaps"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_of_the_gaps) position. It is interesting and mysterious that quantum mechanics suggests that the Universe is non-deterministc. Superdeterminism denies this in the most boring possible way, by claiming all outcomes that appear random were previously decided by a hypothetical being we can never know anything about. This point of view explains nothing, raises unscientific questions and can never be falsified.

Comment: @Andrew, not that I am a superdeterminist, but isn't the statement "can never be falsified" true for most if not all interpretations of quantum mechanics?

Comment: @Andrew : There is no need for a "being" or consciousness, specifically, to make it work. One could argue Bohmian mechanics is superdeterministic, and it has an understandable, simple generating law. The trouble is (beyond the lack of generality), you can come up with _many_ of these schemes. That's why it's best I think to treat quantum theory as a subjective theory when it comes to the _meaning_ of its mathematical terms (namely $\hat{\rho}$ is knowledge, collapse is information gain, observables are questions/propositions) and that the other questions are about

Comment: "implementation details" we can't/don't have access to. That said, the theory is not devoid of physical content under such, as some might assume: given that the information comes (presumably) from physical objects, by describing how that information behaves when communicated amongst them via physical effects, it thus also gives shape to such effects themselves.